# MongoDB aggregation match conditions fails

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have a problem with aggregation function:

this is a screen from MongoDB Compass:

[image]

Category structure:

```
{
  'title' => 'Sport'
  'articles' => [
            {
            'title' => 'My title'
            'status' => 'published'
            }
  ]
   ....
}
```

In the screen you can see a filter in order to get all categories with at least an article with status published.

In the result I always see also category with `'status' => 'draft'`. I do not understand why this filter is not working.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Share your entity interface, please. You're talking about categories, but your querying articles.

Comment: Hi @zhulien, I have just add the structure.

Comment: `articles` is array of arrays or is this a typo?

Comment: Array of objects

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query. Can you show actual data and the query execution result? A screenshot will do.